# A particular weak subadditivity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, consider the following property.

For all $(x^1, ..., x^n) \in \left(\mathbb{R}^n \right)^n$ such that $f(x^i) \geq 0$ $\forall i \in [1,n]$, and $(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) \in \left( \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \right)^n$, there exists $(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n) \in \left( \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \right)^n$ such that

$$ f\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x^i \right) \ \leq \ \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \ f( x^i ). $$

Let $\Phi$ be the set of functions $\phi$ defined as $\phi(x) := \varphi(x) + a^\top x + b$, with $\varphi$ convex and homogeneous (of some degree), $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then any $\phi \in \Phi$ has the above property.

- I am looking for a strict superset $\Phi$, i.e. $\Psi \supset \Phi$, such that any $\psi \in \Psi $ has the above "weak subadditivity" property.

Comment: There is some issue with your question: Take the (affine) linear function $f(x, y) = x + y - 1$. Then, $f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 0$, but $f(1, 1) = 1$. Hence, you can't find $\beta_1, \beta_2$, such that $f(1,1) \le \beta_1 \, f(1,0) + \beta_2 \, f(0,1)$. That is, $f \not\in \Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your condition is satisfied, if the following implication holds for all $x^i \in \mathbb R^n$, $\alpha_i \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}$:
$$f(x_i) = 0 \text{ for all $i$}\quad\text{then}\quad f\big(\sum \alpha_i \,x^i\big) = 0.$$

Now, we can easily find some functions, that are not in $\Phi$, just take some function, which is everywhere positive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you please explain the idea more clearly? What do you mean by "we can easily find [...], just take [...]"?

Comment: Take $\psi(x) = 1 + \|x\|^{1/2}$ and consider $\Psi = \Phi \cup \{\psi\}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I am implicitly interested in a whole class $\Psi$ of such functions, not in a single example.

Comment: In your answer, do you mean "then $f \left( \sum_i \alpha_i x^i\right) = 0$"?

Comment: Of course. What is a "class" of functions? You could take any exponent on the norm.